# SwiftUI: Tapping the return key of keyboard erases all the form data

Tags: swiftui, keyboard

I have forms in my SwiftUI app. In some of them there is a problem relating to keyboard's return key. After editing the form, when I tap the return key to resign the keyboard it erases all the edited data in the form. I could not find any reasonable cause of this problem. I have many network calls in the app.

Here is the code of the login form:

```
import SwiftUI

struct FormView: View {
    var size: CGSize
    @State private var errorMessage: String = ""
    @State private var isConnectionFailed: Bool = false
    @State private var isLoginActive: Bool = false
    @ObservedObject var viewModel = LoginViewModel()
    
    var body: some View {
        ScrollView(.vertical, showsIndicators: false) {
            ZStack {
                VStack {
                    VStack {
                        Image("Logo Registration")
                            .resizable()
                            .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit)
                            .frame(width: 150)
                        Text("Welcome")
                            .bold()
                            .font(.system(size: 22))
                            .foregroundColor(Color("T1"))
                            .padding(.top)
                        Text("Sign in to continue")
                            .font(.system(size: 18))
                            .foregroundColor(Color("T1"))
                            .padding(.top, 8)
                    }
                    .padding()
                    .padding(.bottom)
                    VStack(spacing: 20) {
                        HStack {
                            Image("Call Us_Menu")
                                .resizable()
                                .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit)
                                .frame(width: 35)
                                .padding(.leading, -10)
                            Divider()
                                .rotationEffect(Angle(degrees: 180))
                                .frame(height: 50)
                            Text("+88")
                                .foregroundColor(.gray)
                                .padding(.horizontal, 10)
                            Divider()
                                .rotationEffect(Angle(degrees: 180))
                                .frame(height: 50)
                            TextField("Mobile Number", text: self.$viewModel.mobileNumber)
                        }
                        .crTextFieldStyle(size: size, height: 50)
                        HStack {
                            Image("Password")
                                .resizable()
                                .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit)
                                .frame(width: 35)
                                .padding(.leading, -10)
                            Divider()
                                .rotationEffect(Angle(degrees: 180))
                                .frame(height: 50)
                            SecureField("Password", text: self.$viewModel.password)
                        }
                        .crTextFieldStyle(size: size, height: 50)
                    }
                    HStack {
                        Text(self.errorMessage)
                            .font(.system(size: 12))
                            .foregroundColor(Color("T2"))
                        Spacer()
                    }
                    .frame(width: size.width/1.2)
                    HStack {
                        NavigationLink(
                            destination: ResetPasswordStepOneView()
                                .navigationBarHidden(isHidden: true)
                        ) {
                            Text("Forgot Password?")
                                .foregroundColor(Color("T1"))
                        }
                        Spacer()
                    }
                    .padding(.bottom, 40)
                    .frame(width: size.width/1.2)
                    .font(.system(size: 14))
                    
                    if self.viewModel.loginModel?.status == "ok" {
                        NavigationLink(
                            destination: ContentView()
                                .navigationBarHidden(isHidden: true)
                                .navigationBarBackButtonHidden(true),
                            isActive: $isLoginActive,
                            label: {
                                EmptyView()
                            }
                        )
                    }
                    
                    Button(action: {
                        if self.viewModel.mobileNumber == "" || self.viewModel.password == "" {
                            self.errorMessage = "Mobile number or password is missing"
                        } else if Connectivity.isConnectedToInternet() {
                            self.viewModel.loading = true
                            self.errorMessage = ""
                            self.isLoginActive.toggle()
                            self.viewModel.fetchWithAF()
                        } else {
                            self.isConnectionFailed = true
                            DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 3) {
                                self.isConnectionFailed = false
                            }
                        }
                    }) {
                        Text("SIGN IN")
                    }
                    .frame(width: size.width/1.2, height: 50)
                    .overlay(
                        RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 8)
                            .stroke(Color("B7"), lineWidth: 1)
                    )
                    .foregroundColor(Color("T2"))
                    Text("Or")
                        .padding()
                    NavigationLink(
                        destination: RegistrationView()
                            .navigationBarHidden(isHidden: true)
                    ) {
                        Text("CREATE NEW ACCOUNT")
                            .foregroundColor(Color("T2"))
                            .bold()
                    }
                    Spacer()
                }
                .frame(width: size.width)
                .padding(.bottom, 170)
                
                if self.isConnectionFailed {
                    ConnectivityError()
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

LoginViewModel:

```
import Foundation
import SwiftUI
import Alamofire

class LoginViewModel: ObservableObject{
    @Published var loginModel: LoginModel?
    @Published var loading: Bool = false
    @Published var isError: Bool = false
    
    @Published var mobileNumber: String = ""
    @Published var password: String = ""
    @Published var isActive = false
    
    func fetchWithAF() {
        let registrationReq = LoginReqModel(phone: "+88" + self.mobileNumber, password: self.password)
        
        let url = AppConstant.signin
        let headers: HTTPHeaders = [
            "Content-Type": "application/json"
        ]
        AF.request(URL.init(string: url)!, method: .post, parameters: registrationReq, encoder: JSONParameterEncoder.default, headers: headers).responseJSON { (response) in
            switch response.result {
            case .success(_):
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    do {
                        self.loginModel = try JSONDecoder().decode(LoginModel.self, from: response.data!)
                        if self.loginModel?.payload?.count ?? 0 > 0 {
                            let encoder = JSONEncoder()
                            if let encoded = try? encoder.encode(self.loginModel) {
                                let defaults = UserDefaults.standard
                                defaults.set(encoded, forKey: AppConstant.loginPayoad)
                            }
                            AppConstant.token = self.loginModel?.payload![0].accessToken ?? ""
                        }
                        self.loading = false
                        if self.loginModel?.status == "ok" {
                            self.isActive = true
                            UserDefaults.standard.set(self.mobileNumber, forKey: "Mobile")
                            UserDefaults.standard.set(self.password, forKey: "Password")
                        }
                        if self.loginModel?.status == "error" {
                            self.isError = true
                        }
                    } catch {
                        print("")
                    }
                }
                break
            case .failure(let error):
                print("working error \(error)")
                break
            }
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: where is ```LoginViewModel()```?

Comment: @swiftPunk I have added my LoginViewModel() in my question. Please have a look.

Answer (score 0):

Your viewModel is recreated every time the view reloads. Try changing it to:
`@StateObject var viewModel = LoginViewModel()`

StateObject (introduced in iOS 14) will ensure the object is only created once per view. ObservedObjects need to be owned by some parent view or class.

Comment: But as StateObject is not available below iOS 14, what I could use in that case? I went through some article and it is said not to use ObservedObject to create instances as you said. Could you please suggest me a good practice in this case? My app behaves wrong maybe cause of this.

Comment: You can place it as a EnvironmentObject. This means it is not always recreated, but you can have only one instance at a time. I did make a tutorial talking about the @ObservableObject behaviour here. Maybe this clarifies things more https://youtu.be/5ryXee_Ye3k